# Comparing to DateTime in EF core is generating date string with 6 decimals in milliseconds

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm doing this query

```
var sourceItems = await this.dbContext.Orders
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(item => item.OrderDate > new DateTime(2019, 1, 1))
.Select(order => new
{
    order.CustomerCode
})
.ToListAsync();
```

and I'm getting this sql query

```
SELECT [o].[CustomerCode]
FROM [Order] AS [o]
WHERE [o].[OrderDate] > '2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'
```

which is failing with

> Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm using EF Core 3.1.5.

If I run the sql query directly it works if I reduce the digits in the millisecond portion of the date from 6 zeros to 3 zeros or less.

How can I get EF Core to even skip the millisecond portion of the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core infers the provider type of the constant values from the other operands. In this particular case, from `item.OrderDate`.

The format of the literal indicates that EF Core assumes `datetime2` provider type (the default mapping for `DateTime` CLR type), while the exception indicates that the actual column type is `datetime`.

To solve the problem, you have to let EF Core know the actual type, for instance adding the following to your `OnModelCreating` override:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Property(e => e.OrderDate)
    .HasColumnType("datetime");
```

Now the query will use the correct `'2019-01-01T00:00:00.000'` literal.

Another improvement is to eliminate the literal and let EF Core bind parameter. This is achieved by putting the `new DateTime(...)` expression into variable outside the query expression tree, and use that variable inside:

```cs
var afterDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1); // <--
var sourceItems = await this.dbContext.Orders
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(item => item.OrderDate > afterDate) // <--
    .Select(order => new
    {
        order.CustomerCode
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```