EF Core parameterized DateTime format is invalid
I'm running a basic query using EF Core on SQL Server using a parameterized query where the query is:
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Created >= @0

And my parameter is:
new DateTime(2024, 10, 1, 16, 47, 15)

EF Core produces the following SQL query:
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable AS [m] 
WHERE [m].[Created] >= '2024-10-01T16:47:15.0000000'

Which causes the following error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know that if I run that query in SSMS and format the date as '2024-10-01T16:47:15' instead of '2024-10-01T16:47:15.0000000' then it works fine -- I dont understand why EF Core is self-sabotaging. Does anyone have any idea?
For the avoidance of doubt:

The Created database field is a datetime NOT NULL
The parameter is a DateTime


How are you executing this?

SOLVED
Having searched for some time before posting on SO, I stumbled on the answer a few minutes later thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393901/175893
The reason is that EF Core presumes that
public DateTime Created { get; set; }

on the entity object is a datetime2 in the database, which has a 100 nanosecond precision, when in fact its actually a datetime which has a 1 millisecond precision (I mean, why wouldnt it presume that? LOL)
So the solution is to give it a Column attribute which defines the underlying data type
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }

